# How to update a table with Php Mysql using a $_get VARIABLE IN WHERE Close

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to create an edit link for my web application.  the update  request doesn't work and oddly I am not getting any error. any ideas please  .Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$id=$_GET["invistID"];

if(isset($_POST['validation']))// the submit buttom
{
 try
 {
  $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE invistigation_en SET     fininvist=:fininvist,rapportinvist=:rapportinvist,status=:status WHERE  invistID=:invistID');

$data =array(
':invistID'=>$id,
':fininvist'=> $_POST['fin'],
':rapportinvist'=> $_POST['rapport'],
':status'=> $_POST['status']

);
$req->execute($data);
echo "success ...";
 }catch(PDOException $e){
 echo "Error ... :".$e->getMessage();
   }

header('Location:invistigation.php');// 

}
?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($bdd->ErrorInfo())` and `var_dump($req->ErrorInfo())` to see if there are errors in your prepare or execute calls.

Comment: Don't know if that header will work as you are echoing pass/fail messages before it

Comment: How do you know that the update isn't working, is it from the database or from the page not behaving the way youd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Debug is an important step when you build applications. When you write code, some times, application behavior is not as you expects. This is your case. At this time, you should **isolate** your issue and **fix** it.

To **isolate issue** they are some techniques. At this time you don't know why this code don't run. Then you should **identify program check points** and check if, at this points, all is as you expect.

For your code:

1. **Check all page parameters** have expected values. `var_dump( $_POST )`
2. **Check all query parameters** you send to `execute` are right: `var_dump( $data )`
3. **Print errors** as @andrewsi suggest: `var_dump($bdd->ErrorInfo())`  `var_dump($req->ErrorInfo())` .
4. If problem persist **raise your own errors**: change `Update` word by `XXXX`, execute and check if some errors appear.
5. **Remove redirect** ( header('Location ... ), change it  by `die("end")` to see all page errors.

good luck, and please, let us know, finally, where your error was.

Comment: Thanks All, I figure out the problem . The $_GET value was lost during the load so i had to store it  in a $_SESSION variable and now it works like a charm.  I was able to see that while using the var_dump fonction so thumbs up to you guys